# Show/hide divs with same class

Tags: jquery

I have four images and four divs. When image 1 is clicked, div 1 should appear and all others should be hidden, etc. Each div has the same class name.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".DataList").hide();
        $(".DataList:first").show();    
        $(".trigger").click(function() {
            $(".DataList").hide();
            $(".DataList").eq($(this).index()).show();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="LinkBar">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
               <a class="trigger" href="#"><img src="Package1.gif" /></a> </td>
            <td>
               <a class="trigger" href="#"><img src="Package2.gif" /></a> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="DataList">
    <div class="Description">
        <ul class="Package">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="Hidden">
            1 </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="DataList">
    <div class="Description">
        <ul class="Package">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="Hidden">
            2 </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited, based on your full markup:

```
$(".DataList").hide();
$(".DataList:first").show();
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    $(".DataList").hide();
    $(".DataList").eq($(this).closest("td").index()).show();
});
```

The above solution relies on the cell index in which the `.trigger` links appear.

[**Try it here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kDHyQ/)

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/closest/
- http://api.jquery.com/eq/
- http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: My triggers are links in table cells, in a div. Do I need to remove the table and the div?

Comment: You really should post your true markup structure. I based my answer on the structure that you posted, I will need to modify it based on your actually markup.

Answer (score 1):

Give different ids to div and use `$("document.getElementById('specificDivId')").hide();`

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to identify corresponding links and targets.

If they are ordered, then you could use the relative position, though usually it would be best to add `id` fields to both, so that they can be matched if they get out of order.

Try naming all `.trigger` fields with `id="trigger-n"` (n=1,2,3,4), and `.DataList` fields with `id="DataList-n"`.

Then you can match one with the other like so:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
  var cTriggerID = $(this).attr('id').replace(/^.*-(\d+)$/, '$1');
  var cDataList = $('#DataList-' + cTriggerID);
  cDataList.slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks but modifying the id is not an option at this time.

Comment: @YBW: In general this approach is more robust than relying on structural layout, what restricts the IDs?  In addition, as karim said, always try to ensure that you put the proper structure down and state restrictions on your question.  As people will spend time answering in a way that is not appropriate.